# How can i compute the lowest and highest possible mem addresses available from a kernel just after booting?

Tags: memory, assembly, kernel, ram

After the boot up in real mode, i would like to figure out the lowest and highest
possible memory addresses i can use. I assume i need to find out
the actual size of the ram installed on the machine then computing
the addresses should be simple (but just for fun, how would i do it :)). 
Then i could use these addresses as
the base and limit of my gdt right? That way after loading the gdt,
going to protected mode, and setting up my segments. Ill have all the memory
available to play with.

Comment: Also, see here: http://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_Memory_(x86)

Answer (score 1):

Real mode by definition can't address all the memory. You'd have to switch to protected mode first, with a safe GDT limit, scan the memory, then adjust the descriptor limit(s) accordingly.

As for detecting memory, just try reading from increasing physical addresses until it exceptions. Designate a selector for that, reset the descriptor in a loop, and go ahead.

Comment: You wouldnt happen to know how to tell WHEN that specific exception happens, and how to handle it would you?

Comment: When - when you read from physical address that's unavailable. How to handle it - conclude that there's no more memory and stop the loop :) Not sure which exception will it be though. Poke around.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: What kind of "exception" do you get when you read frmo a "physical address that's unavailable"? (Reference?)